# How to give an option a description slash commands discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I installed discord.py using `python3 -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`.

[pic of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wObd1.png)

This is main.py

```
guild_id = 964345157480747029

import discord
from discord import app_commands

class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents = discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False #we use this so the bot doesn't sync commands more than once

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced: #check if slash commands have been synced 
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id)) #guild specific: leave blank if global (global registration can take 1-24 hours)
            self.synced = True
        print(f"We have logged in as {self.user}.")

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'test', description='A test slash command') #guild specific slash command
async def slash2(interaction: discord.Interaction, text: str)
  await interaction.response.send_message(f'You said "{text}"!')

client.run('token')
```

The slash command works, but I want the text option to have a description that says
"Text to repeat".

I used this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgN9U1wBTAg) and got most of my code from [here](https://github.com/Digiwind/Digiwind-Videos/blob/main/DPY%20Slash%20Commands.py).

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using slash commands I'd recommend `py-cord` instead of `discord.py`.

- [Installing](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/installing.html)
- [Basic slash command](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot-with-slash-commands)
- [More detailed slash commands](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/app_commands/slash_basic.py)
- [Options](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/app_commands/slash_options.py)

An example would be

```
import discord
from discord import option

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.slash_command(name="test", guild_ids=[000000000000000000])  # replace with your guild id
@option(
    "text",
    str,
    description="Enter some text"
)
async def test_command(ctx, text):
    await ctx.respond(f"You wrote: {text}")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of adding a description to app command arguments.

1. by using the `app_commands.describe(arg=desc)` decorator.
2. by creating a docstring for the function which takes the argument descriptions as well as the command description from there.
   Both of them are shown below.

```py
 ​    ​@​app_commands​.​command​(​name​=​"item"​) 
 ​    ​@​app_commands​.​describe​( 
 ​        ​choices​=​"Do you want to buy or sell, in fact?!"​, 
 ​        ​item_name​=​"Which item, in fact?!"​, 
 ​    ) 
 ​    ​async​ ​def​ ​get_item​( 
 ​        ​self​, 
 ​        ​interaction​: ​discord​.​Interaction​, 
 ​        ​choices​: ​app_commands​.​Choice​[​str​], 
 ​        ​item_name​: ​str​, 
 ​    ): 
 ​        ​"""Get item information and buy/sell orders. 
  
 ​        Args: 
 ​            interaction (discord.Interaction): the interaction that invokes this coroutine 
 ​            choices (app_commands.Choice[str]): buying or selling? 
 ​            item_name (str): item name to search for 
 ​        """
         pass
```