# Problem with slash command options. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm have trouble with slash command options, namely I'm trying set the minimum and maximum value of the entered number.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test")
@app_commands.Argument(
    num=[
        app_commands.Argument.min_value(1),
        app_commands.Argument.min_value(5)
    ]
)
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, num:int):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"You choose number: {num}")
```

Console log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\derekbot\!src\bot.py", line 81, in <module>
    app_commands.Argument.min_value(1),
TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable
```

I've tried to do it with other methods as well, but they don't work too.

Comment: `min_value` and `max_value` are attributes, not methods as you have them currently written. Have you considered working with `py-cord` as an alternative to `discord.py`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73132093/how-to-give-an-option-a-description-slash-commands-discord-py

Comment: @nathanliang Discord.py is the main library for developing discord bots in Python. It has the most support and is the most popular. I would personally recommend sticking with discord.py for most people, even though I think the way most libraries have implemented slash commands horribly.

Answer (score 2):

mate.

I deem I've found a solution.
You can just use app_commands.Range class in order to set Min and Max values.

```
@bot.tree.command()
async def test(ctx: discord.Interaction, value: app_commands.Range[int, 5]):
    await ctx.response.send_message(f"Your number: {value}")
```

- `Range[int, 10]` means the minimum is 10 with no maximum.
- `Range[int, None, 10]` means the maximum is 10 with no minimum.
- `Range[int, 1, 10]` means the minimum is 1 and the maximum is 10.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it according to docs, you need to set the attributes in the decorator instead of calling it like you did.

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="test")
@app_commands.Argument(
    name="num",
    min_value=1,
    max_value=5
)
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, num: int):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"You choose number: {num}")
```

You can find docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=min_value#discord.app_commands.Argument.max_value).

I also recommend you stick with discord.py.

Comment: After writing suggested code, function still doesn't work.

Console error:
"TypeError: Argument.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'"